# Differential Equation for calculating concentration of mixture

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-modeling

I am self studying linear algebra at the moment and I have been stuck at this section of the chapter.

The questions says:

> A 10,000 cu-ft room contains 20% carbon dioxide. Pure oxygen will be pumped into the room at a rate of 5 cu-ft/min. The well-mixed air escapes from the room at a rate of 5 cu-ft/min.
>
> How long will it take to reduce the carbon dioxide level to 5%?

I have tried to set up my dA/dt equation like this

> dA/dt = 5 - (5A/10000)

And

> A(t) = 10000 - (1/e^t)^(1/2000) + C

A(0) is 8000 so...

> C = -1999

And that gives me

> A(t) = 8001-(1/e^t)^(1/2000)

But when i try to find when the carbon is at 5%, which means the oxygen is at 10000(0.95) = 9500. But whatever number i try, it either gives me 8000 or an error on my calculator.

I can't seem to find my mistake on this particular question. So if stack exchange could lend me a little help, that'd be awesome!

Comment: Why do you have the constant $5$ in your differential equation?

Comment: rate-in minus rate-out method. it's pouring at 5 cu-ft pure oxygen and pumping out 5 cu-ft of total air. A/10000 is the concentration of oxygen that's being pumped out. 5 is the amount of volume of air that is being pumped out.

Comment: OK, then. What happened to the $5t$ term that you should’ve had after integrating? Leaving aside the correctness of your differential equation, the $A(t)$ that you have on the next line doesn’t match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define that $A$ is the number of cubic feet of oxygen in the room.  Your solution for $A(t)$ is not correct.  The $C$ should multiply the $e^{-t/2000}$ term.  Then you get $$A(t)=10,000+Ce^{-t/2000}\\C=-2000\\A(t)=10,000-2000e^{-t/2000}$$
and now solving for $A(t)=9500$ should be no problem.

Comment: Oh I see it now! I was separating them and then integrating them. It seems that I need more practice using that simple method lol. I used the integrating factor method to get to your solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ross Millikan has already explained the errors in your solution in [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2926075/265466). I think, however, that you’re better off working directly with the carbon dioxide volume $V_{\text{CO}_2}$ and concentration $\phi_{\text{CO}_2}$. There is no new carbon dioxide entering the system, so the resulting equations should have fewer terms. Why make things harder for yourself than they need to be? The magic gases mix instantly, so the instantaneous rate at which carbon dioxide volume changes is simply $$\dot V_{\text{CO}_2} = - 5 \phi_{\text{CO}_2}.$$ To get the change in concentration, divide by the constant total gas volume: $${\dot\phi}_{\text{CO}_2} = -\frac1{2000}\phi_{\text{CO}_2}.$$ You can take it from here, I’m sure.